# vba for selecting multiple different active cells with offset condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and I have vba code for activecell with offset codition.
The following code selects few cells based on offset condtion.
I want to get selected same number of cells if more than one cell or multiple cells are selected.
please help me.
Thanks in advance

```
ActiveCell.Offset(, 0).Resize(1, 2).Select
```

If i select cell b1, then on running the code it selects b1 and c1.
I want solution for multiple random cells if selected in column b, the corresponding value should be selected.

Comment: `I want to get selected same number of cells if more than one cell or multiple cells are selected.` - clarify please, some example would be helpful. Btw, `ActiveCell.Offset(, 0)` the same as `ActiveCell`.

Comment: HI simoco, thanks for your response.

Comment: HI simoco, thanks for your response.If select a1 and run the code it will select a1 and b1. If I select a1 and a3 and a7 then cells a1b1 and a3b3 and a7b7 should be selected.

Comment: what should be if you select, say, `A1:B2` and `C1:D2`?

Comment: Actually, I want to make selections only in column B. The selections should be made only in column B. It may be multiple cells likd b1 or b2 or b7. If these cells are selected the corresponding rows have to be selected on running code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If select a1 and run the code it will select a1 and b1. If I select a1 and a3 and a7 then cells a1b1 and a3b3 and a7b7 should be selected.

**UPDATED:**

Follow up from comments:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ar As Range
    Dim rngAE As Range, cell As Range

    With Selection
        For Each ar In .Areas
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = ar.Resize(1, 2)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, ar.Resize(1, 2))
            End If
        Next ar

        Set rngAE = Intersect(.Cells, Range("A:E"))
        If Not rngAE Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In rngAE
                Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A" & cell.Row & ":E" & cell.Row))
            Next cell                
        End If
    End With

    rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: hi simico, it works great. I modified little bit to suit my needs. Thanks a lot simico.

Comment: Hi simico, one more question. Suppose i have data in a1:e1. If i select c1 or d1 or b1, i should be able to select all data from a1:e1. Please help

Comment: use this one line: `If Not Intersect(Selection, Range("B1:D1")) Is Nothing Then Range("A1:E1").Select`

Comment: Hi simico, the data is in columns("O:Z"). And i have modified your code and paste below. Please look at the modification and tell me where to insert the code that you have given later i,e. If Not Intersect.......and My code is Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Range
With Selection
For Each ar In .Areas
If rng Is Nothing Then
Set rng = ar.Resize(, 12)
Else
Set rng = Union(rng, ar.Resize(, 12))
End If
Next ar
End With
rng.Copy
Range("A24").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: actually I can't uderstand what are you trying to do? `If select a1 and run the code it will select a1 and b1. If I select a1 and a3 and a7 then cells a1b1 and a3b3 and a7b7 should be selected.` or `If i select c1 or d1 or b1, i should be able to select all data from a1:e1.`?

Comment: Sorry for confusing.Actually i got perfect answer from you for the first question. 2nd question was for further alteration of 1st question. Please just tell me where should i insert the code If not Intersect(............

Comment: I would tell you as soon as I undersand what you are going to do:) So, if user select `b1` or `c1` or `d1`, than select `a1:e1`. Otherwise (if user doesn't select `b1` or `c1` or `d1`), e.g. user selects `a1` and `a3` - than select `a1:b1` and `a3:b3` - am I correct?

Comment: If user selects a1 then a1:e1 should be selected or if b1 selected a1:e1 should be selected or if c1 is selected then a1:e1 should be selected. I mean to say if any cell is selected in range a1:e1, then a1:e1 should be selected. This should happen if one cell is selected in a row and even if multiple cells in different row is selected.

Comment: so, is it what you need?)

Comment: should i post different post for another question?. Actually i need answer for another question.

Comment: yes. It would be better to post new Question. Somebody (or maybe I) could help you. Btw, don't forget to add some examples in you new question

Comment: If u can help me here. Please look into following. This is extension to my 1st question where in you have solved my problem. If user selects a1 then a1:e1 should be selected or if b1 selected a1:e1 should be selected or if c1 is selected then a1:e1 should be selected. I mean to say if any cell is selected in range a1:e1, then a1:e1 should be selected. This should happen if one cell is selected in a row and even if multiple cells in different row is selected.

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer? as I see it do exactly what you need

Comment: if user selects `a1` and `a3` and `a7`, then `a1:e1` and `a3:b3` and `a7:b7` would be selected

Comment: Hi simico, i tried your updated code. But on run there is no change in cells and no error message. If i select b1 then a1:e1 should be selected.

Comment: I just tested it and when I select `b1` it selects `a1:e1` as you need. Can't figured out what's wrong. Can you say 1) what cells you select before core run, 2) what cells seleted after code run 3) and what cells are you expecting should be selected.

Comment: Hi simico, sorry for troubling you. Just now i tried it worked perfectly. when i select any cell between a1 to e1, on code running it selects perfect range that i needed. but it works only for a1:e1. How about if i select any cell in 2nd row or 3rd row etc for a:e.

Comment: I absolutely can't understand what you need. If you select say b2 then a2:e2 should be selected? If yes - try me updated answer

Comment: Hi simico, sorry for not responding to your previous msg since i was not feeling well. thanks for your reply. I will be back after testing your new code

Comment: hi simico, the above code is working perfectly. If i select a cell any cell in a:e, on running code it is working perfectly. that much is required for me. If i run code in any cell otherthan a:e , then two cells are selected.I dont want to two cells to be selected. Please help.